# Multicast recv from another device connected to same switch not working despite traffic shown on tcpdump

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, multicast

I'm trying to receive multicast data from an embedded device connected to the same switch as my desktop and am unable to receive multicast messages on my recv app below.
When I do a tcpdump or run Wireshark against the interface connected to the switch, I see the packets show up but for some reason they don't in my app.

I'm using INADDR_ANY for the interface address.
Could someone shed some light on why the messages would be on Wireshark/Tcpdump but not received by the application?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UDP_PORT 5403
#define UDP_GROUP "225.0.0.1"
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     struct sockaddr_in addr;
     int fd, nbytes;
     socklen_t addrlen;
     struct ip_mreq mreq;
     char msgbuf[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
     u_int reuse_port = 1;

     // Create a socket
     fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
     if (fd < 0)
     {
        perror("create socket failed");
        return -1;
     }

     // allow multiple sockets to use the same PORT number
     if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_port, sizeof(reuse_port)) < 0)
     {
        perror("Reusing port number failed");
        return -1;
     }

     // set up destination address
     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
     addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     addr.sin_port = htons(UDP_PORT);
     if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
     {
        perror("bind");
        return -1;
     }

     // Set the recvfrom timeout after 1 s
     struct timeval tv;
     tv.tv_sec = 2;
     tv.tv_usec = 0;
     if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv)) < 0)
     {
         perror("Error setting recvfrom timeout\n");
         return -1;
     }

     // use setsockopt() to request that the kernel join a multicast group
     mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(UDP_GROUP);
     mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
     {
        perror("setsockopt");
        return -1;
     }

     addrlen = sizeof(addr);
     printf("Begin recvfrom(...) infinite loop\n");
     while (true)
     {
         nbytes = recvfrom(fd, msgbuf, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);
         if (nbytes < 0)
         {
            printf("recvfrom timeout\n");
         }
         else
         {
            printf("message received: %s\n", msgbuf);
         }
     }
     return 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you try without the port reuse? Are you sure that the server terminates its message with a `\0`? Are all the messages lost?

Comment: Are you sure you're listing on the correct port and multicast address?  I'm able to receive traffic sent to 225.0.0.1:5403 with this code.